# PHP Scrape breaks outside of localhost

Tags: php, localhost, live, scrape

So I'm trying to scrape some data from a site and I got the whole script working on localhost. Uploaded it to live server and it then returns an empty variable.

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
function getElementByIdAsString($url, $id, $pretty = true) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $loaded = @$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

    var_dump($loaded);

    if(!$loaded) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load $url");
    }

    // Obtain the element
    $element = $doc->getElementById($id );

    if(!$element) {
        throw new Exception("An MEMEelement with id $id was not found");
    }

    if($pretty) {
        $doc->formatOutput = true;
    }

    // Return the string representation of the element
    return $doc->saveXML($element);
}

$test = getElementByIdAsString('http://www.google.nl', 'index-banner');
var_dump($test);
?>
```

Comment: I checked that url, and there is no element with an id of `index-banner` so they must have changed the DOM since you developed on localhost.